# Is there any efficient way to generate random date_time from range to 10 days back from now?

Tags: c++, date, c++11, boost, posix

I wanted to know if there is any possible way to to generate random posix::time from range of now to 10 days back ?

I thought about something like:

```
using namespace boost::posix_time;
second_clock now = second_clock::local_time();
second_clock back = now - hours(240);
```

Doing so I would have local date and date from 10 days back, but how could I generate some random date from that period ? I know that's probably as easy as it could be, but I am out of ideas ;/

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood, but why don't you just replace `240` with a randomly generated integer?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using a uniform_int_distribution and making a generic utility that can create random timestamp generators for varying time windows:

**<kbd>Live On Coliru</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using boost::posix_time::ptime;
using boost::posix_time::minutes;
using boost::posix_time::seconds;
using boost::posix_time::hours;

int main() {
    auto rng = std::mt19937 { std::random_device{}() }; // correctly seeded random generator

    auto date_selector = [&](boost::posix_time::time_duration window = boost::posix_time::hours(24*10), ptime now = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time()) {
        auto start = now - window;
        unsigned size = (now - start).total_seconds();
        return [=]() mutable {
            return start + seconds(std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned>(0,size)(rng));
        };
    };

    auto seven_days = date_selector(hours(7*24));
    std::cout << "seven_days:\n";
    for (auto i = 10; i; --i) std::cout << "\t" << seven_days() << "\n";

    auto ten_minutes = date_selector(minutes(10));
    std::cout << "ten_minutes:\n";
    for (auto i = 10; i; --i) std::cout << "\t" << ten_minutes() << "\n";
}
```

Prints, e.g.

```
seven_days:
    2016-Dec-27 22:32:13
    2016-Dec-30 10:02:14
    2016-Dec-27 13:14:59
    2016-Dec-29 22:44:16
    2016-Dec-30 17:28:37
    2016-Dec-31 05:21:38
    2017-Jan-01 10:33:44
    2017-Jan-01 06:50:51
    2016-Dec-28 09:52:12
    2016-Dec-29 12:35:50
ten_minutes:
    2017-Jan-02 13:34:52
    2017-Jan-02 13:38:25
    2017-Jan-02 13:34:19
    2017-Jan-02 13:37:44
    2017-Jan-02 13:38:51
    2017-Jan-02 13:39:34
    2017-Jan-02 13:41:18
    2017-Jan-02 13:41:05
    2017-Jan-02 13:35:32
    2017-Jan-02 13:37:08
```

Answer (score -1):

if i understand you correctly you want to get a random timestamp between today and 10 days back.

i would advise you to take 10 days in millisecs and just pick a random number in that range and subtract it for now's timestamp.

unfortunately, rand cannot generate a random number that big.
therefore, you can create such timestamp in parts, and subtract the current timestamp from it.

```
    unsigned int days_in_milli, hrs_in_milli, mins_in_milli, secs_in_milli, num_milli_back;
srand(time(NULL));
num_milli_back = rand() % 1000;

days_in_milli = (rand() % 10) * 86400000;
hrs_in_milli = (rand() % 24) * 3600000;
mins_in_milli = (rand() % 60) * 60000;
secs_in_milli = (rand() % 60) * 1000;

cout << ((unsigned)time(NULL) - (days_in_milli + hrs_in_milli + mins_in_milli + secs_in_milli + num_milli_back)) << endl;
```

hope that was helpful